# Flot xaxis Ticks not showing

Tags: flot

OK I have a flot stacked bar chart displaying some information, now this all works perfectly except for the xaxis.

At present instead of showing the data I want it to show it just shows a column number on every other column.

Below is my code for the xaxis:

```
 var options = {
    series: {stack: 0,
             lines: {show: false, steps: false },
             bars: {show: true, barWidth: 0.5, align: 'center',},},
    xaxis: {ticks: [[1,' Yesterday'], [2,'Two'], [3,'Three'], [4,'Four'], [5,'Five'], [6,'Six'], [7,'Seven'], [8,'Eight'], [9,'Nine'], [10,'Ten'], [11,'Eleven'], [12,'Twelve'], [13,'Thirteen'], [14,'fourteen']]},
    xaxis: { tickColor: 'transparent' }
};

$.plot($(css_id), data, options);
});
```

And here is the configure section:

```
  xaxis: {
                show: true, // null = auto-detect, true = always, false = never
                position: "bottom", // or "top"
                mode: null, // null or "time"
                color: "#990000", // base color, labels, ticks
                tickColor: null, // possibly different color of ticks, e.g. "rgba(0,0,0,0.15)"
                transform: null, // null or f: number -> number to transform axis
                inverseTransform: null, // if transform is set, this should be the inverse function
                min: null, // min. value to show, null means set automatically
                max: null, // max. value to show, null means set automatically
                autoscaleMargin: null, // margin in % to add if auto-setting min/max
                ticks: null, // either [1, 3] or [[1, "a"], 3] or (fn: axis info -> ticks) or app. number of ticks for auto-ticks
                tickFormatter: null, // fn: number -> string
                labelWidth: null, // size of tick labels in pixels
                labelHeight: null,
                reserveSpace: null, // whether to reserve space even if axis isn't shown
                tickLength: null, // size in pixels of ticks, or "full" for whole line
                alignTicksWithAxis: null, // axis number or null for no sync

                // mode specific options
                tickDecimals: null, // no. of decimals, null means auto
                tickSize: null, // number or [number, "unit"]
                minTickSize: null, // number or [number, "unit"]
                monthNames: null, // list of names of months
                timeformat: null, // format string to use
                twelveHourClock: false // 12 or 24 time in time mode
            },
```

I have tried changing pretty much everything and looked at different posts, but nothing seems to change the values.  I can do simple things like change the color etc and so i am wondering if i have got something wrong.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've doubled your xaxis configuration, so the second one overwrites the first.

This:

```
xaxis: {ticks: [[1,' Yesterday'], [2,'Two'], [3,'Three'], [4,'Four'], [5,'Five'], [6,'Six'], [7,'Seven'], [8,'Eight'], [9,'Nine'], [10,'Ten'], [11,'Eleven'], [12,'Twelve'], [13,'Thirteen'], [14,'fourteen']]},
xaxis: { tickColor: 'transparent' }
```

Should be:

```
xaxis: {
    ticks: [[1,' Yesterday'], [2,'Two'], [3,'Three'], [4,'Four'], [5,'Five'], [6,'Six'], [7,'Seven'], [8,'Eight'], [9,'Nine'], [10,'Ten'], [11,'Eleven'], [12,'Twelve'], [13,'Thirteen'], [14,'fourteen']],
    tickColor: 'transparent'
},
```

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly, would never have found that so much appreciated, funny though as soon as somebody points it out it makes sense.